# Logging Into GitHub From Terminal Authenticate Message

Tags: git, github

When I try to push -u origin master and enter my github username and password, I get the following output:

```
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use 
a personal access token instead. remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15- 
token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information. fatal: 
unable to access "..." : The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Because of this, I generated a personal access token. I was then told to use this token in the "Keychain Access" app on my Mac. However, I am supposed to change the "github.com" entree there and I do not currently have one. What should I do about this?

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account

Comment: did that but still not changing anything

Answer (score 0):

Make sure and remove your previously cached credentials with:

```
printf "protocol=https\nhost=github.com"| git credential-osxkeychain erase
```

Then you can try again, enter your new credentials, which will be cached.

Comment: Still not doing anything, my current git version is 2.23.0. Is that a problem?

Comment: @MomchilNikolov What `git config credential.helper` returns?

Comment: It returns osxkeychain

Comment: @MomchilNikolov And do you see anything when typing `printf "protocol=https\nhost=github.com"| git credential-osxkeychain get`?

Comment: Nope, I saw nothing

Comment: @MomchilNikolov Then the next git pull (for a private repository) would ask for your credentials which would then be cached by the osxkeychain.

Comment: you would think, but I keep getting that error message and it doesn't cache anything

Comment: I tried entering the personal token instead for my password, and I get: remote: Permission to <myusername>/Test.git denied to <myusername>.

Comment: @MomchilNikolov Can you try with a new Personal Access Token?

Comment: I already tried, doesn't make a difference

Comment: @MomchilNikolov For testing, does `git ls-remote https://<GitHubUsername>:<Token>@github.com/<GitHubUsername>/<repoName>` work?

Comment: That seemed to have added something to do the keychain! However, I am still getting the remote: Permission to <myusername>/Test.git denied to <myusername> when trying to authenticate

Comment: @MomchilNikolov Strange,... I would be curious to know what GitHub support has to say about that (https://support.github.com/request).